# How do i handle sub sequential URL calls in RxJS that pass data to each other?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I have a call to a service, that potentially returns to me a queue URL, if the server is to busy to handle the response.

I'm writing a service in angular, to handle these types of calls, and i'm struggling to figure out what kind of `RXJS 6+` operator to handle this for me.

This means that i want to make a fallback, that if the response returns to me a queuing URL, i will subscribe to this call, and retry it until i get an answer.

The wait time can be up to 30 seconds (`< insert frustrations here>`).

From what i can tell from the rxjs documentation page, i need to use the `concatMap` operator, and somehow `retry` the call until i get the correct response? Maybe with some `delay` operators to restrict the amount of calls?

I found this [snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ec6wed?embed=1&file=index.ts) from https://www.learnrxjs.io/.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any code of where you are up to? also an example of the potential response payload. These will help get you a faster answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive call structure, so you need to write a recursive observable. You haven't provided exact response structures so I can't give exact code but at a high level it will look like this:

```
getQueuedResponse<T>(url) {
  return this.http.get<T>(url).pipe( // fetch the first URL
    switchMap(res => 
      (res.queueUrl) // if queued (your actual queue indicator may be different)
        ? this.getQueuedResponse<T>(res.queueUrl) //then recurse (your actual next url may be different or it may be the original url again)
        : of(res))); // else break (what you actually return here may be different)
}
```

you can add in a delay if you'd like with a simple timer:

```
getQueuedResponse<T>(url) {
  return this.http.get<T>(url).pipe( // fetch the first URL
    switchMap(res => 
      (res.queueUrl) // if queued, recurse after 5 seconds
        ? timer(5000).pipe(switchMap(t => this.getQueuedResponse<T>(res.queueUrl))
        : of(res))); // else break
}
```

Alternatively, if your needs are a little different and you can just call the same URL over and over, you can view this is a polling problem:

```
pollForResponse<T>(url) {
  return timer(0, 5000).pipe( // start right away then emit every 5 seconds
    switchMap(i => this.http.get<T>(url)), // request the URL
    takeWhile(r => !!r.queued), // keep taking while it's queued
    last() // only emit the last response
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll come back to edit this if my assumption is incorrect but assuming you're getting back a payload that looks something like this when you need to redirect your request to a queue:

```
{
    queue: true
    url: "http://myqueue.com"
}
```

vs when you just get a response:

```
{
    queue: false
    data: { "foo": "bar" }
}
```

The way to redirect your request might look like this

```
http.get<DataModel>('http://the-original-url').pipe(
    switchMap(dataModel=>{
        //did we get queued?
        if (dataModel.queue) {
            //make a subsequent request and retry it 3 times
            return http.get<QueueResponseModel>(dataModel.url).pipe(retry(3))
        } else {
            //return an observable that emits the desired data
            return of(dataModel.data)
        }
    })
)
```